# Trying to send user video from telegram bot using curl

Tags: ios, curl, video

using command:

```
curl -s _X POST "https://api.telegram.org/bot<token>/sendVideo -F chat_id=<chatID> -F video="@myvideo.mp4"
```

sends a video file "myvideo.mp4" ok to the telegram user chatID from my bot with token value "token"  .

However unlike when sending from the telegram-cli  https://github.com/vysheng/tg (I used previous to bots being available) the file appears black when opened on an iPad or iBook telegram client. However if I save it from there to the Camera Roll I can open the file and play the video there. On an iMac desktop telegram client I can click the file and open it with QuickTime player OK. The file is 640x480 and about 3Mb.
Sending messages or photos using a similar technique works fine.
Any ideas what I need to tweak to get this to work properly? I have seen lots of examples for sending messsages or photos, but can find none for sending videos.

Comment: I have exactly same problem did you find any solution?

Comment: I have the very same problem using the following command:
curl -s -X POST https://api.telegram.org/<token>/sendVideo -F chat_id=<chatID> -F video=@/Users/mauro/video.mp4 -F video=@/Users/mauro/bot/jumping.mp4 -F duration=5 -F caption="My Video"

Comment: I have same problem, I use CURL in PHP

Answer (score 1):

try this

`curl -F video=@"/path/to/video/file" https://api.telegram.org/bot<token>/sendVideo?chat_id=<chat_id>`

Answer (score 0):

`curl -s -F chat_id=<chatID> -F video=@"myvideo.mp4" https://api.telegram.org/bot<token>/sendVideo`

Comment: The answer would be more useful if you can add some explanation along with the code.